# Discord bot reacts just sometimes

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I recently been struggling with a small and easy to make script on my discord bot. The script is supposed to make the bot react to whatever image (and only image) is posted to a certain channel. Thing is the bot reacts just SOMETIMES and it really seems random when it reacts, the script never really functioned as intended but at some point it did work on every picture of the channel, after a restart I did deliberately it again functioned randomly.

```
client.on("message", message => {
if (message.author.bot) return;
let prefix = ';';

if (message.channel.id == showoffid){
  const collector = new Discord.MessageCollector(
    message.channel,
    m => m.author.id === message.author.id,
    {}
  );
  collector.on('collect', message => {
    if (message.attachments.size > 0) {
     message.react('✨')
      .catch(console.error);
      return;
    }
  })
}

if (message.channel.id == hundoid){
  const collector = new Discord.MessageCollector(
    message.channel,
    m => m.author.id === message.author.id,
    {}
  );
  collector.on('collect', message => {
    if (message.attachments.size > 0) {
     message.react('')
      .catch(console.error);
      return;
    }
  })
}
}
```

Comment: whats you question  ? And you dont need use collector there.
You reaction work random, because its start when, some one send message and then send message with image. Like fist message its a trigger to await message with image

Comment: Well my question is basically why it does work randomly or "What to do in order not to make it work randomly", Something that you just attempted to answer me, I think that's obvious. Well,if I don't need collector for that then I assume all I need is a simple "if" statement to check if the post is actually an image, i think this is built-in on discord.js, is that what you mean? is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code and then its stop work random.

```
client.on("message", message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    let prefix = ';';

    if (message.channel.id == showoffid){
            if (message.attachments.size > 0) {
             message.react('✨')
                .catch(console.error);
                return;
            }
    }

    if (message.channel.id == hundoid){
            if (message.attachments.size > 0) {
             message.react('')
                .catch(console.error);
                return;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: serves me right using tools i don't really get how they work. Thanks for the help, for now it seems like it works as intended.